# Find average for a column in each row php

Tags: sql

I want to iterate through a table and find the averages for some columns (such as average teleop score, average auto score, average climber score) for each row in a table.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT AVG(auto_upper_attempt),  AVG(auto_upper_score),  AVG(auto_lower_attempt),  AVG(auto_lower_score), AVG(teleop_upper_attempt), AVG(teleop_upper_score),  AVG(teleop_lower_attempt),  AVG(teleop_lower_score)
FROM play
where team_id = 1;
```

But this only gives me one team's averages, not them all. And if I get rid of the where statement, like this:

```
SELECT AVG(auto_upper_attempt),  AVG(auto_upper_score),  AVG(auto_lower_attempt),  AVG(auto_lower_score), AVG(teleop_upper_attempt), AVG(teleop_upper_score),  AVG(teleop_lower_attempt),  AVG(teleop_lower_score)
    FROM play
```

It gives me the average for all teams in one column, not in a separate row for each team.

Comment: you need `group by`

Comment: Use `GROUP BY team_id` to get the average for each team.